# Change image (svg) on click

Tags: jquery, image, svg, onclick, raphael

I'm trying out Raphael + vectron, and i'm trying to change a svg image with a button click.

This is (of course) not possible due to that when the svg is rendered it's rendered as path:

```
<path cx="100" d="M35.269,257.154C34.393,245.68099999999998,45.438,234.091,48.492,223.00799999999998C53.634,204.34099999999998,54.985,185.004,60.041 and so on...... " stroke="none" fill="#9d49ce" style=""></path>
```

Below is the code, which would work if I was working with a normal image (like .png), but the question is how can I change the svg image with Raphael (and vectron).

html:

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="avatarBox" class="bgBox_blue">
  <div id="charBody" class="svg-file" data-svg="img/body1.svg"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="toolBox">
  <div class="toolboxArea">
    Byt kropp<br/>
    <button id="moveLeftBtn"><</button>
    <button id="moveRightBtn">></button>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
```

js:

```
$('.svg-file').vectron({
    scale: 1
  }).ajaxSuccess(function(){
    $('svg').attr({
      'height': ($('svg').attr('height')*120)/100,
      'width': ($('svg').attr('width')*110)/100,
    });

    var paper = $('.svg-file').data('vectron').paper;
    var unicorn = paper.top;

    $('.bodyBg').live('click', function(){
      unicorn.attr({
        fill: $(this).val(),
        cx: 100
      });
    });
  });


var moveRightBtn = $('#moveRightBtn');
    moveRightBtn.on('click', function(){
        var newImage = 'body' + (AvatarGenerator.eyes + 1) + '.svg';
        $('#charBody').attr('data-svg','img/' + newImage);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the path inside svg tag.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<path cx="100" d="M35.269,257.154C34.393,245.68099999999998,45.438,234.091,48.492,223.00799999999998C53.634,204.34099999999998,54.985,185.004,60.041 and so on...... " stroke="none" fill="#9d49ce" style=""></path>
</svg>
```

It will behave as an svg element. I tested it on Chrome and IE.

So in your case, given an HTML file with this line :

```
<div id="charBody" class="svg-file" data-svg="img/body1.svg"></div>
```

Calling `$('.svg-file').vectron();` creates a child svg element for `charBody` with content loaded from the file, which is displayed in the page.

I would say instead of calling vectron you can directly add the content from the svg element string to that div's `innerHTML` where you wish to add SVG.

vectron was last updated a year ago, so I don't have high hopes from it. Besides you only need to change an svg on buttonclick which can be done without vectron easily.